# Naive Bayes with triple class?

Tags: methods, classification, naivebayes

I am working on a thesis regarding the behavior of characters in the game using the naive bayes method. What I have learned, Classes or labels in Naive Bayes methods usually only have two classes, such as "yes" and "no". Is it possible if the given class is more than two? like "attack", "run", "defend" and what is the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is very possible for a multi-class situation.

Consider `y` can be `1,2,3`. The Bayes Theorem can be generalised as:

```
P(y=1|X)=P(X|y=1)*p(y=1)/(P(X|y=1)*p(y=1)+P(X|y=2)*p(y=2)+P(X|y=3)*p(y=3))
```